# Edge browser: "XMLHttpRequest: Network Error"

Tags: angular5

Technologies used for my application: Asp.Net MVC 5, Angular 5.

Application works well in IE 11 and Chrome, but not in Edge browser.

In Edge developer tools, I see this error message 
"XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80700013, http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/9/F/B9FF9327-7A72-4165-BF91-9B7EEB6C579B/DeviceList.json".

Other than this message, Edge does not provide me with any other details.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and not using Angular CLI to build. Also did not include polyfills file.

Please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: It would be best to search for "Network Error 0x80700013" and see if any of the results apply to your situation.

Comment: Is the error *only* present in the Edge Developer Tools - does the site actually work apart from that message?

Comment: Hi Andrew, yes the error is only present in Edge and not in other browsers. Yes I'm search for the error and trying to apply but none worked so far. Actually I couldn't find a lot of information related to this error. Thank you!

Comment: If you look at that json file, it appears to be something to do with Edge emulating various phones - if you look at the Emulation tab, perhaps a reason for the problem will be apparent.

Comment: I looked at this file and this list is for mobile device. In my case, I'm getting this error in my desktop system when I debug the application using Visual Studio 2017. So not sure if this list is relevant to the scenario and that is part for confusion.

Comment: I'm getting this debugging in vs2017 and I'm not using Angular... (just a plain mvc site)...

Answer (score 2):

Are you running this behind a corporate firewall? Can you check if you can successfully request "http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/9/F/B9FF9327-7A72-4165-BF91-9B7EEB6C579B/DeviceList.json" in Chrome or another browser? If you cannot, then it might be a network related issue.

For instance, I get this error at my workplace when testing in Edge, as my workplace firewall blocks various Microsoft download and update sites, including the "*download.microsoft.com*" domain.

Comment: What to do if json file http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/9/F/B9FF9327-7A72-4165-BF91-9B7EEB6C579B/DeviceList.json can be downloaded in Edge browser. Do we need to add this file in the source code or something else is required to get out of this issue? I am also facing same issue.